# MySQL 8: show deprecated error only as warning

Tags: migration, mysql-8.0, errors, collation, error-handling

I'm migrating MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0.32.

I know character set utf8mb3 and its collations are deprecated. But we have lots of functionality and data with utf8mb3,
and we don't have more time to change them to utf8mb4.

So, I expected that, as it's only "deprecated", my PLs and other funcionality works, but with "deprecated warning".
But I got this error:

```
ERROR 3778 (HY000): 'utf8mb3_spanish_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an appropriate collation instead.
```

I don't understand a deprecated issue raises an error. I expected a warning, but not an error.

So, my question is: is it possible (any flag, variable, configuration, etc.) to change "deprecated" issues to warnings or warning level?

I know the main and right fix is to change to utf8mb4. Ok, but I have a challenge in other way.

Thanks in advance.